# Fixed Table Header with Scrollbars On GridView in IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I  am trying to implement a fixed header feature addition to an existing sub class of GridView, SGridView.

My issue is that with the solution listed below, the scroll bar appears below the header row and looks tacky. I would prefer that the scrollbar runs vertically through the header to the footer. The only issue is that this means that the first couple of rows would be covered by the header because the scrollbar height isn't accounting for the inclusion of the header row (I assume this is a side effect of absolute positioning). Any thoughts on how to correct that?

My solution consists of the following:

```
<div class="IEScrollDiv">
 <table class="GridView">
   <thead>
     <tr> <th clas="GVHeader"> my header row</th> </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     ...
   </tbody>
 </table>
</table>
```

More or less, added additional code into the Render() method to wrap the table in a div that can scroll. Nothing too fancy. Then I configured the table to render , , and  tags for accessibility.

Since adding scrolling to tbody is undefined in IE, I could not utilize it to create a fixed header (lame). In addition, the expression css rule has been deprecated from IE8 so I couldn't use that approach either (plenty of tutorials online utilizing it).

So, I added javascript to to absolutely position the header row, via it's class GVHeader.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe add a bottom margin to the scroll div .. then move the header row into the margined area???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might end up wanting to implement something similar, thought I would post my solution.

I couldn't get the exact look I wanted (scrollbar running through the header, but rather beside it).

I simply had the gridview render a empty div take with a class on it that makes it x number of pixels high to include gap space for the header. Then just repositioned the header on top of that div. Now the scrollbar includes the header row as part of the height.

so the markup looks like this in the end

```
<div class="IEScrollDiv">
 <div class="EmptyDiv"></div>
 <table class="GridView">
   <thead>
     <tr> <th clas="GVHeader"> my header row</th> </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     ...
   </tbody>
 </table>
</table>

.EmptyDiv
{
    height: 33px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```